# What is the recommended way of REST API url pattern for this?

Tags: rest, url, routes

For example, each `video` has one and only one owner.

If I want to add the function of `listVideosByOwner`, which of the following pattern is preferred? (more RESTful)

1. `videos/owner/${ownerID}`
2. `owner/${ownerID}/videos`
3. `videos/byOwner/${ownerID}`

Does anyone have ideas about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way would be to use a query parameter for the `ownerId`:

```
GET /videos?ownerId=${ownerId}
```

This is the widely used filter-collection-by-property pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer solution nr.1, because the videos are bound to the owner. If you call the method to see all videos of one owner, it makes sense sending the ownerID via REST call.

Answer (score 0):

This would ideally be an HTTP GET resource and I would design my resource URL in the following way:

```
GET /videos?ownerId=theOwnersId
```

1. This makes sense because you're querying the server for videos. Querying is an Idempotent operation and analogous to a database retrieve; hence, it must be an HTTP GET.
2. The REST resource being returned should always be plural as opposed to singular because the server is thought to have a collection of the resource that you're trying to query. Hence, **videos** and not **video**.
3. When specified with just `/videos`, an ideal REST resource should return a list of all the videos that it possesses. In your case what we need is to be able to query based on the *ownerId*. Hence, we must add the query parameter `ownerId` to your the REST URL.

   - While implementing this REST resource on the server side, I would check if the request URL has a query parameter. If yes, I must return all videos associated with that owner. If no query parameter exists, I would return a structured data set of all the videos I have.

Further reading - http://www.restapitutorial.com/